# How to convert a spaceless data into tab delimited

Tags: list-manipulation, matrix, data-structures, conversion

I have a data set in form of:(this is just an example)

```
1324501020
3241030205
4332020134
```

the data are stored in a text file (e.g. data.txt) but I need to convert them into a matrix format such that each number be place in a cell like this:

```
1 3 2 4 5 0 1 0 2 0
3 2 4 1 0 3 0 2 0 5
4 3 3 2 0 2 0 1 3 4
```

or in terms of `List` in Mathematica, I need to have

`{{1,3,2,4,5,0,1,0,2,0},{3,2,4,1,0,3,0,2,0,5},{4,3,3,2,0,2,0,1,3,4}}`

in other words, the final data set supposed to be a matrix of numbers.
Any idea??

Answer (score 1):

`(IntegerDigits@ImportString["1324501020
    3241030205
    4332020134"]) // Flatten[#, 1] &`
list data no need  spaces?

If you wanna string still add them
`Riffle[#, " "] & /@ Characters /@ StringSplit["1324501020
   3241030205
   4332020134"]`

If data in txt file, import as list first.

Comment: the data are stored in a *.dat file and they supposed to be numbers and not string.

Comment: @Amin Just `IntegerDigits/@Import@"E:\\Users\\Quaternions\\Documents\\test.dat"`

Comment: I couldn't use those syntax. I've imported the file into Mathematica but the operation by IntegerDigits is change them into numbers from string. I need to have a numerical matrix at the end. May be I'm missing some thing here.

Comment: I used    `IntegerDigits/@Import@"E:\\data\\data.txt","List]` and it worked but it gave me some errors

Comment: @Amin It needs to be IntegerDigits/@Import["E:\\data\\data.txt","List"]. The shorthand @ can only be used when a function has one argument and no options. Actually, you only need IntegerDigits@ (rather than .../@) since IntegerDigits is listable.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
TableForm[IntegerDigits[{1324501020, 3241030205, 4332020134}]]
(* ->
   1    3   2   4   5   0   1   0   2   0
   3    2   4   1   0   3   0   2   0   5
   4    3   3   2   0   2   0   1   3   4
*)
```

This will make the list look like a matrix table form. [HyperGroups](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/6648/hypergroups) is correct in trying `IntegerDigits`. What kinds of operations will you be performing on the results or is this purely formatting for display purposes?

Comment: Those are data from a testing company and numbers are responses to items provided by test takers. They have some kind of scanners for reading scantrons and store responses after each other without space. I want to analyze responses so I need to have them separated in which responses to each item be like a variable or in terms of matrix data, be a column.

Comment: Welcome to the site, and thanks for your answer! I made a few edits to your post in order to conform to site norms. I'm sure you'll quickly get the hang of it. :)

Comment: @OleksandrR. I hope to get the hang of this.

Answer (score 0):

```
MatrixForm[
     Read /@ StringToStream /@ Characters[#] & /@ {"1234" , "5678"}]
```

[image]

perhaps a bit cleaner..

```
 IntegerDigits /@ Read /@ StringToStream /@ {"1234", "5678"}
```